# Proving a test is UMP for Uniformly distributed random variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, likelihood-ratio, neyman-pearson-lemma

Let $X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ be a sample of size n from the PMF
$$P_N(x) = {1 \over N},\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x = 1,2,...,N;N \in \mathbb{N} $$

Show that
$$
\varphi(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = \begin{cases}
1 & x_{(n)} > N_0 \text{ or } x_{(n)} \leq α^{{1 \over n}}N_0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
is a UMP size $α$ test of $H'_0 : N = N_0$ against $H'_1 : N = N_0$.

**Work from my side:**

- Proved that $P_N(X)$ has Monotone Likelihood ratio in statistic $T(x) = \max(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = x_{(n)}$
- Proved that the following test
  $$
  \varphi(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = \begin{cases}
  1 & x_{(n)} > N_0 \\
  \alpha & x_{(n)} \leq N_0
  \end{cases}
  $$
  is UMP size α for testing for $H_0 : N ≤ N_0 \text{ against } H_1 : N > N_0$.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag if this is some sort of homework. To show this is UMP against $H_1':N\ne N_0$, one approach is to show $\varphi$ is UMP against both the alternatives $N>N_0$ and $N<N_0$.

Comment: Perhaps see [this Q & A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117844/ump-for-u0-theta-simple-x-simple-hypothesis/441875#441875), a continuous analogue.

Comment: @StubbornAtom No it's not a part of any homework. I am just studying for an examination by myself.